# Why don't have I the choice to create a drop down list in data validation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have already created many drop down list using data validation but for a few days now I absolutely can't. I don't understand what may have changed nor how I can get it working back?

When I click on data validation I get:

[image: Data Validation Settings]

And here are the options I get:

[image]

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I just vierified that I still have these functions. I'm not sure if I'm on the latest version of excel though, but it is possible something was broken in the last update.

Comment: Please go to File > Account, check the version number and share it with us. Besides, you may go to Control Panel to repair Office.

Comment: Yeah, that dropdown list you displayed looks more like the criteria versus the "allow" list....